# DISTINCT with LEFT JOINS

Tags: mysql

I am fetching records from different tables and to avoid duplicate row I am using `GROUP BY` clause, `DISTINCT` is faster than `GROUP BY` so I tried my heavily `JOIN` query with `DISTINCT` (as a replacement of `GROUP BY`) but it fetches duplicate records as well. Any idea how could I achieve optimized, fastest & efficient query.

**Query sample:**

Here index is set on `projectId` field in projects table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*, p.projectId as proId, plat.*, con.*, dom.*, sta.*, tech.*, role.*, pimg.*, c.*, dur.* 
                FROM projects p 
                LEFT JOIN projectplatforms pplat ON p.projectId = pplat.projectId JOIN platforms plat ON plat.platformId = pplat.platformId 
                LEFT JOIN projectcountries pcon ON p.projectId = pcon.projectId JOIN countries con ON con.countryId = pcon.countryId 
                LEFT JOIN projectdomains pdom ON p.projectId = pdom.projectId JOIN domains dom ON dom.domainId = pdom.domainId 
                LEFT JOIN statuses sta ON p.statusId = sta.statusId 
                LEFT JOIN projecttechs ptech ON p.projectId = ptech.projectId JOIN technologies tech ON tech.techId = ptech.techId 
                LEFT JOIN projectroles prole ON p.projectId = prole.projectId JOIN roles role ON role.roleId = prole.roleId 
                LEFT JOIN projectimages pimg ON p.projectId = pimg.projectId
                LEFT JOIN clients c ON p.clientId = c.clientId 
                LEFT JOIN durations dur ON p.durationId = dur.durationId 
                WHERE p.featured = 1 
                ORDER BY p.year DESC
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a "duplicate" record that is returned when using `DISTINCT`?  Note that *every column* in the resultset must be identical for `DISTINCT` to take action.

Answer (score 0):

With DISTINCT mysql will return all unique rows. It is not the same if you used GROUP BY on one or some part of the columns. You probably want to use GROUP BY not DISTINCT.

Comment: If he uses GROUP BY only for some columns, he will not be able to retrieve the other columns. Only columns in the group by clause and aggregate functions can be used in the select clause.

Comment: It's not portable sql but will work in MySQL, other column values are not deterministic though. But if that makes sense depends on use case.